# SSAO in my unity games has flickering lines at the top and right side of the screen

Tags: unity, hlsl, graphic-effects, ssao, image-effects

I've tried both the built-in unity ambient occlusion that comes with the post-processing stack, as well as another one ported from the Microsoft MiniEngine by someone: https://github.com/keijiro/MiniEngineAO.
Both of them have the same issue pictured below with these dark lines and the occlusion on the faces around the lines seem to flicker as the camera moves.

[image]

I've been trying to solve this issue by using the Microsoft MiniEngine AO and changing the compute shader. In one of my attempts, I changed the output of the shader from the calculated occlusion:
`Occlusion[OutPixel] = lerp(1, ao, gIntensity);`
to the depth texture UV to be sampled: 
`Occlusion[OutPixel] = QuadCenterUV.x;`
(QuadCenterUV probably being the center of the UV to sample for the 4 depth texture samples:)

```
// Fetch four depths and store them in LDS
#ifdef INTERLEAVE_RESULT
    float4 depths = DepthTex.Gather(samplerDepthTex, float3(QuadCenterUV, 
DTid.z));
#else
    float4 depths = DepthTex.Gather(samplerDepthTex, QuadCenterUV);
```

and this was the output:
[image]

With a similar effect on the Y axis. I think that may be the cause, as the distortion of the UVs matches the distortion of the effect. 
I don't know how to fix this, because I don't have enough knowledge about RWBuffers or compute shaders. 
My terrain is generated by a noise function as a 2D array, constructed into a mesh, the mesh runs `Mesh.RecalculateNormals()`, and then is sent to the Mesh Filter.
 
What is the issue here, and how can I fix it, or can anyone fix it for me?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you eventually find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have no clue what could be causing this, even simple linear coordinates of the UV get distorted. I can only assume it is some sort of bug somewhere further up the line.

Comment: Actually, I did find a solution. https://github.com/keijiro/KinoObscurance seems to work for me.